# SPO - Hosted Add-In: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: javascript, jsom, date-time, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to save data in format: dd/mm/yyyy to SPO server. My regional settings is set to **alert(regionalSettings.get_localeId());** //1026. How to solve this problem ?

**This is my code:**

```
oListItem.set_item("HolidayDateFrom", "13/03/1992");
oListItem.set_item("HolidayDateTo", "20/04/1992");
```

**This is xml schema for my DateTime field:**

```
Field Name="HolidayDateFrom" 
ID="{8b84ee43-e6eb-4ab9-9dc7-184d2a4b29e1}" 
DisplayName="HolidayDateFrom" 
Type="DateTime" 
Format="DateOnly" />
```

**Error is:**

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

What i insert here, thank you previously...

Comment: so if you run your code, how is it stored now ?

Comment: When i store the date in format (mm/dd/yyyy) - 13/11/1992, its allright

Comment: What is the 11th day of the 13nd month ??

Comment: i think in the example he just mixed them up ;) meant to be opposite way. you want  (dd/mm/yyyy)  20/11/1992 but only accepts american version of (mm/dd/yyyy) 11/20/1992 is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a string into a datetime field. It's set to explicitly `Type="DateTime"` so you need to put in that type of object not string. Do:

```
var dt = new Date(1992, 03, 13);
oListItem.set_item("HolidayDateFrom", dt);
dt = new Date(1992, 04, 20);
oListItem.set_item("HolidayDateTo", dt);
```

More info on "Date" object can be found here: 
http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions

Also make 100% sure you have the correct local that is set on the site:

Click Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Regional Settings -> Select Bulgarian from the Locale drop down box -> Click OK